# Add url image to word file causes trouble in C#

Tags: c#

I want to transfer the word image with the following code, but I think because the image is loaded late, I get an error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Where is my mistake?

```
// Word uygulamasını oluşturuyoruz.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
// Yeni doküman oluşturuyoruz.
WordApp.Documents.Add();
// word açılıyor.
WordApp.Visible = true;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;

var link = "https://zeminprogram-debb.restdb.io/media/uydu.png";

doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(link, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality by using DocX library

and here is the sample code :

```
var myImageFullPath = "C:\tmp\sample.png";
using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"docs\HelloWorldAddPictureToWord.docx"))
{
  // Add an image into the document.    
  Image image = document.AddImage(myImageFullPath);

  // Create a picture (A custom view of an Image).
  Picture picture = image.CreatePicture();

  // Insert a new Paragraph into the document.
  Paragraph title = document.InsertParagraph().Append("This is a test for a 
  picture").FontSize(20).Font(new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS"));
  title.Alignment = Alignment.center;

  // Insert a new Paragraph into the document.
  Paragraph p1 = document.InsertParagraph();

 // Append content to the Paragraph
 p1.AppendLine("Check out this picture ").AppendPicture(picture).Append(" its funky 
 don't you think?");
 p1.AppendLine();

 p1.AppendPicture(picture);

 // Save this document.
 document.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately,
again the same problem,

no problem retrieving from folder 
but still giving the same error when retrieving from url

```
  var myImageFullPath = "https://zeminprogram-debb.restdb.io/media/uydu.png";
        using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@Application.StartupPath + "\\dene.doc"))
        {
            // Add an image into the document.    
            Xceed.Document.NET.Image image = document.AddImage(myImageFullPath);

            // Create a picture (A custom view of an Image).
            Picture picture = image.CreatePicture();

            // Insert a new Paragraph into the document.


            // Insert a new Paragraph into the document.
            Paragraph p1 = document.InsertParagraph();

            // Append content to the Paragraph
            p1.AppendLine("LOGO").AppendPicture(picture).Append(" its funky  don't you think?");



            p1.AppendLine();

            p1.AppendPicture(picture);
            document.Save();
            // Save this document.

        }
```

Comment: Refer this URL By this way also you can insert URL into Word File       https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hrojasara/insert-picture-with-hyperlink-in-word-file-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: unfortunately, 
the solution you proposed didn't work either, 
I wonder
the site to which the image belongs, such as blocking may be available?